# Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I have just begun learning Objective-C, coming from a VB .Net and C# .Net background.  I understand pointer usage, but in Objective-C examples I see the asterisk placed in several different places, and search as I might, I have not been able to find an answer as to why this is.  Every search I try turns up all kinds of explanations about pointers (which I really don't need), but not a single mention of the reasons/effects of the different placements of the asterisk.  Here are some examples I've seen:

```
NSString *string;
NSString * string;
(NSString *) string;
NSString* string;
```

What do these different positions of the asterisk mean?  I'm sure it's a simple answer but it's frustrating not being able to find it in any of the Apple tutorial and reference documentation or online so far.

Can someone please end my misery and answer this perplexing question?  Thanks!

Comment: @john_5101 If you put four spaces before your code-like text, it will treat it as code and make it look correct (I believe that is the answer to the problem to which you elude in your question).

Comment: Can we take this as an opportunity to just randomly declare one of them the "right' way and stop this nonsense?

Answer (score 33):

There is no difference, however you should be aware that only the first "token" (so to speak) defines the type name, and the * is not part of the type name. That is to say:

```
NSString *aString, bString;
```

Creates one pointer-to-`NSString`, and one `NSString`. To get both to be pointers, do either:

```
NSString *aString, *bString;
```

or:

```
NSString *aString;
NSString *bString;
```

Comment: Since the original question was about placement of `*`, I edited your answer slightly to reduce confusion.

Comment: …and of course you can't declare an NSString variable that is not a pointer (outside of POC dialect), so the first code example would not compile.

Comment: Would `NSString* aString, bString` create 2 pointers to NSStrings?

Comment: Formatting-wise, I am having this debate with my colleagues. As you pointed out, you cannot create two variables on one line if the asterisk is associated with the class type and not the variable. They say that the asterisk should be touching the class type and not the variable.

Answer (score 24):

```
1.  NSString *string;
2.  NSString * string;
3.  (NSString *) string;
4.  NSString* string;
```

1, 2 and 4 are exactly identical.  It's all style.  Pick whatever you want, or mix it up.

Choice #3 has another meaning also, it's used in casting.  For example:

```
t = (NSString *)string ;
```

will cast `string` to an `NSString` pointer.

But choice #3 is the syntax you'd probably use in a .h file or in the function definition in a .m file.  Inside an actual function, in code which is "run" it has a different meaning.

Comment: Although it's a valid typecast, there should never be a need to explicitly cast an object to NSString* -- if you're downcasting from id or void*, you can do the cast implicitly, and if you're upcasting from a subclass (such as NSMutableString), you can also do so implicitly.

Comment: +1, but statement 3 is actually a nop - you'd likely not want to use that line anywhere.  You would use it as part of an expresion to cast the `string` to an NSString*, but it's not valid as a declaration.  Of course, I'm not familiar with Objective-C, so if there's a use for statement 3 in that dialect of C, please let me know that I'm spouting nonsense, and I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Agreed.  And thanks, good point.  But syntactically, it's a cast.  I just wanted to point it out because there definitely will be times where the OP poster will see it.

Comment: Actually, just to clarify for Michael Burr, defining a member function in ObjC is like:  
- (void)doSomething:(NSString *)param1 { }
This is why everyone says it's a valid declaration, because it is, in this situation.

Comment: There is a need to explicitly cast to NSString if you start with an NSObject and cast to a number of different types.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to keep it consistent as opposed to mixing it up? At least within the context of a single project?

Answer (score 19):

There is no difference — it's a matter of style. They all declare a variable called `string` that's a pointer to an NSString. The parentheses are necessary in some contexts (particularly method declarations) in order to clarify that it's a type declaration.

Comment: I think you mean there's no difference in spacing around the asterisk, but as others have pointed out, the 3rd line is (by itself) a cast to an NSString* (which one might use if string is an `id` of CFStringRef) or possibly part of an Objective-C method declaration. To me, at least, your meaning was clear.

Comment: I nevertheless prefer the last form (coming from a C++ background): it demarcates clearly the type and the object. Here is a nice little discussion about this topic by Stroustrup: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace

Answer (score 7):

```
1.  NSString *string;
2.  NSString * string;
3.  (NSString *) string;
4.  NSString* string;
```

1,2 and 4 are equivalent. The C language (and the Objective-C superset of C) specify a syntax that is insensitive to white space. So you can freely add spaces where you choose as a matter of style. All relevant syntax is delimited by non-whitespace characters (e.g. `{`, `}`, `;`, etc.) [1].

3 is either a type cast (telling the C compiler to use the `NSString*` type regardless of the declared type of `string`. In Objective-C, type casting of object instances is rarely necessary. You can use the `id` type for variables that can reference instances of any object type.

In method declarations, syntax 3 (sometimes without the ending semicolon) is used to declare the type of method parameters. An Objective-C method may look like this:

```
- (void)myMethodThatTakesAString:(NSString*)string;
```

In this declaration, the type of the argument named `string` is type `NSString*` (the leading `-` indicates an instance method as oppose to a class method). A method declaration with more than one parameter might look like this:

```
- (void)myMethodTakingAString:(NSString*)string andAnInteger:(NSInteger)intParam;
```

[1] This is compared to languages like Python which use whitespace as a block delimeter.

Answer (score 6):

it doesn't matter where you put your asterisk, all statements create pointers of type NSString.

when using multiple variable names in one line you have to write the asterisk for each variable though.

```
NSString * nsstring, * nsstring2;
```

Comment: ... which is one of the ugliest things in C and should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, where the `*` is placed in a pointer declaration is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

No difference, whitespace placement is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference.  NSString* mystring and NSString *myString are identical.

Answer (score 3):

the * works the same way as it does in standard C.

this is a nice primer on putting the * in different places and what it does:
http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Answer (score 2):

there actually all equivalent: a pointer to an nsstring!!

Answer (score 2):

1, 2 and 4 are equivalent and define a pointer to an NSString.  My personal preference is to emulate K&R as much as possible, so I like to use `NSString *string;`

`(NString*)string;`  though a valid statement, doesn't really do anything by itself.

```
$ cat foo.m
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void foo()
{
    NSString *string;

    (NSString*) string;  // doesn't do anything
    42;   // doesn't do anything either
}

$ gcc -Wall -c foo.m
foo.m: In function 'foo':
foo.m:7: warning: statement with no effect
foo.m:8: warning: statement with no effect
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference between these.

Comment: There is a stylistic difference which make a lot of difference from code readability perspective. @me1974's answer is correct ... it should be as shown by apple

Comment: well making own version of a recommended style can not have other effect but to decrease readability for majority of developers ...

Comment: Again, subjective, and not a majority. Conventions have shifted over time and can be seen even in Apple code.

Answer (score 0):

in the xcode4 documentation sample code you can see 3. all the time, for example in MoveMeView.m

```
#if 1

- (void)growAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

#define MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 0.15

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS];
placardView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f); 
/*
 Move the placardView to under the touch.
 We passed the location wrapped in an NSValue as the context.
 Get the point from the value, then release the value because we retained it in touchesBegan:withEvent:.
 */
NSValue *touchPointValue = (NSValue *)context;
placardView.center = [touchPointValue CGPointValue];
[touchPointValue release];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any differences in the alternatives 1, 2 and 4 to the computer but there are to other readers of the code.

Since explanations like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521382 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16040884 and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_pointers.htm use the first alternative:

`1.  NSString *string;`

and all extra variables need their own asterisk like in:

`NSString *aString, *bString;`

my humble suggestion is that we use alternative 1 as a standard.