# Question about syntax when creating objects/variables

Tags: objective-c

I'm wondering if there really is a difference between these two lines for example:

NSNumber* myNumber = ......
NSNumber *myNumber = ......

I ask, because I'm very new and have been reading a book on it, and it seems the author started off putting the asterisk in front of the object's name, but then later on started put it after the data type.

Is it just a format issue?

Comment: No, it's not an issue - just matter of style

Comment: This was previously answered in [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

NO

And you can even use:

```
NSNumber * myNumber =
```