# What is the difference between where an asterisk "*" is in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

I'm new to XCode, coming from C#. What is the difference between the two following syntax examples, specifically the location of the asterisk?

```
UITabBarItem* tabBarItem
```

and

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem
```

When do you use one syntax over the other?

Comment: Please search the site before posting a question - avoiding duplicates helps keep all of the answers on one page, making the site more useful.

Comment: Also take a look at [C Pointers](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both mean the same. There is no difference between the two and it is a matter of preference. I personally prefer the second way because it looks cleaner when have multiple pointers.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItemOne, *tabBarItemTwo ; // Looks cleaner :)
```

than

```
UITabBarItem* tabBarItemOne, *tabBarItemTwo ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, just preference.  Both declare a pointer to a UITabBarItem.