# difference declaration objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

i was wondering, whats the difference?

between
NSString* myString;

and
NSString *myString;

Comment: Answered in [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

Comment: One of them has the space before the asterisk, and the other has the space after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between them. It's just a matter of what you like.
My favorite style is NSString * myString.

Comment: great, thanks .. i was wondering .. i like the NSString* myString; the most ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no different between them.
The * tells us that the variable myString is a pointer that is pointing to a NSString object.

I would prefer NSString *myString because it tells us clearly that myString is pointing somewhere.

Think of * as a "Is a pointer >".