# Objective-c syntax - Class *var vs Class* var

Tags: objective-c, class, syntax, ivar

I'm from a PHP background and I'm new to Objective C. 
I get that an asterisk before a var identifies it as a pointer. However what does an asterisk AFTER a CLASS NAME mean? I've seen it both ways and it's not a mistake. Is a style difference with the same meaning?

```
Class *var  
Class* var
```

Comment: Didn't this question just get asked less than 24 hours ago???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Smarta$$ Roger - How do you accept answers on here?

Comment: @Helpful Dave... I didn't see that when I searched for an answer before posting. Yeah it's same question, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same meaning. Using the asterisk after the class name is somewhat misleading in case of multiple variable declarations; for example, in this line:

```
Myclass* a, b;
```

the asterisk only applies to a. But some people argue that * is a part of the datatype, therefore belongs together with the class name.

Answer (score 2):

The two statements are semantically equivalent. It's a matter of preference. One thing to note:

```
Class* var1, var2;
```

That statement declares var1 to be `Class*` but var2 `Class`. To declare both of them a pointer to Class:

```
Class *var1, *var2;
```

Which is why I prefer grouping the asterisk near the variable name, even though it's less "correct" to the type you're declaring.

Answer (score 1):

Just like C and C++, it's stylistic.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace is not significant in this case so you can write either.