# Objective C - Difference Between VARType* vt and VARType *vt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

What is the differenct between the following:

(Assume we have a class calculator)

```
Calculator* calc;
Calculator *calc;
```

Also what is the need for pointers? Is it not possible to omit the star?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between those two declarations, you could also do `Calculator * calc` if you're feeling adventurous.

As far as if you can omit the star, no, you cannot. It is a carry over from C and shows that calc is a pointer to a Calculator, and not a Calculator itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the 2 declaration is just an preference for typing. 
Every thing on computers uses pointers. You need pointers java, c#, etc use pointers. 
No is not posible to omit the star.