# Objective C pointer use

Tags: objective-c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why)
>   [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

Is there any difference between

```
NSString* foo = @"I'm a string";
```

and

```
NSString *foo = @"I'm a string";
```

I've always used the latter way, but wasn't sure if there actually was a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no difference at all. It's the same as in **C** language. They are both pointers to `NSString`.

Some people prefer the later form because it makes clear what variable is the pointer. I.E.:

```
int* i, j;
// i is a pointer
// j is not a pointer

int *i, j;
// makes clearer that i is a pointer while j is not

int *i, *j; // both pointers...
```

Check out a [C-FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/decl/charstarws.html) on the topic.

Comment: Is there an industry standard way of doing it?  Is it just user preference?

Comment: No. There is no standard at all. This discussions goes way back to the old C times.