# Objective C: NSString* myVar; vs. NSString *myVar;

Tags: objective-c, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

I am confused, is there a difference between declaring a pointer as `NSString* myVar;` and `NSString *myVar;` ?

i.e. is the location of the asterix significant?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no difference. However I think that 2nd one is more readable.

```
int* a, b;
int *a, b;
```

In the 2nd one it is clear that `a` is a pointer but `b` is not. But in the 1st line it looks like both `a` and `b` are pointers which is not true.

But still, this is a personal choice and there is NO difference from compiler's point of view in the two lines.

Comment: Including the fact that both lines are abominations, and a and b should be split up on separate lines before disaster strikes.

Answer (score 3):

No.