# Where to put the * Asterisk on Objective C Pointer Variables

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Just a quick question - what is the difference (if any) between:

```
NSObject* myObj
```

and

```
NSObject *myObj
```

and even

```
NSObject * myObj
```

?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  A pointer's a pointer's a pointer.

Comment: the compiler just doesn't care

Comment: it is a style preference. some development teams are rather picky about these things. you should try to be consistent throughout your code. otherwise there is no difference as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a technical point of view, it doesn't matter.

Personally I use the last option (* in the middle), but it's a matter of personal taste.

A corner case would be the definition of multiple inline declarations, like

```
NSObject *a, b
```

as opposed to

```
NSObject *a, *b
```

The first case will produce a pointer to `NSObject` and a `NSObject` (which of course is forbidden and it wouldn't compile), whereas the second one will produce two pointers.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is this is totally a style issue, however, a team of developers may wish to match style and certain [open source] projects may have guidelines they enforce. For example, here's Github's Objective-C conventions: https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions

(they use `NSObject *myObj`)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that Apple does use this style, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both variations represent a pointer readable by Objective-C.